# How to call a stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have written single stored procedure for `insert`, `update`, `delete`, and `select`.  The procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[artdetails1]
(
    @artdetailId int,
    @artDescription varchar(50),
    @artShortdesc varchar(50),
    @artValidity varchar(50),
    @artStatus varchar(50),
    @StatementType varchar(50)

)

AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INFOartdetails(artDescription,artShortdesc,artValidity,artStatus)
                values(@artDescription,@artShortdesc,@artValidity,@artStatus)   

        END

    IF @StatementType = 'Select'
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM artdetails
        END 

    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE artdetails SET
                artDescription=@artDescription,artShortdesc=@artShortdesc,
                artValidity=@artValidity,artStatus=@artStatus
                where artdetailId= @artdetailId
        END

    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE artist SET @artStatus= 'not available';
        END
  END
END
```

But I am confused about how I can check the statement type in C# code and call this procedure. Please help. I am new to SQL.

Comment: Run "exec artdetails1" to call it

Comment: You are asking for a lesson on how to use ADO.NET, which is a bit large of a topic for a SO answer. (assuming you mean how to call this proc from C#-- it isn't clear what you're asking)

Comment: A stored procedure that performs updates _and_ selects is not a good design - separate each action into it's own procedure.

Comment: No. I am asking about how can i check Statementtype

Comment: You want help with C# code, why are you showing us some ugly MSSQL stored procedure?

Comment: If you dont want to give answer or if u dont know it then please dont comment.and please read instructions of stack overflow before using words like ugly nd all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should *NOT* perform selects and updates in one procedure.  You should have separate procedures for inserts, updates, selects, and deletes.

However, here's how you'd call the insert procedure from C#:

1. Create a connection
2. Create a command
3. Add parameters
4. Execute the command
5. Capture the results (if applicable

Example code:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString) 
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("artdetails1", conn)
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artdetailId", detailID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artDescription", description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artShortdesc", shortDesc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artValidity", validity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artStatus", status);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatementType","Insert");

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // No output to capture for an `INSERT`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure call example (assuming you're using SQL server). Having one stored procedure for everything is exception from a rule that good programmer is a lazy one:

```
  using(var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQL2008;Database=foo;Integrated Security=true")) {
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[artdetails1]", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatementType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Insert";
    // set all other parameters
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic process of calling the stored proc from c# is outlined below.

```
String connstr = @"Data Source=myserverName;Initial Catalog=myCatalogName;Integrated Security=True";
String statementType = "Select"; //just an example

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Parameters.Add("artdetailId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@artDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "myArtDescription";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@artShortdesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "myArtShortDesc";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@artValidity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "myArtValidity";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@artStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "myArtStatus";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatementType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StatementType;

sql conn.Open();

if StatementType = "Select" {
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Use DataReader to access the data here.
)
else if StatementType = "Insert" || StatementType = "Update" || StatementType = "Delete"
rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note: The code is not tested.